# Visual Studio 2015 freezes whole PC on build repetendly

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Sometimes if i Debug a C++ program in Visual Studio 2015 it freezes my whole PC so i have to restart it. Windows doesn't respond to anything even not to commands like CRL+ALT+DEL. Even other programms i have open dont respond anymore and everything freezes.

When this happens Visual Studio is loading a DLL as seen in the bottom left corner and then everything just freezes and only the Windows loading cursor still spins.

Comment: That's a good one. Which version of Windows are you using? Please don't say ME. Next suggestion is that you check to be sure that your antivirus isn't blocking something. Sysinternals's Process monitor might also be helpful.

Comment: Does it also lock over a hello world program?

Comment: 1.I am using Windows 10 Pro. 2. I am using Bit Defender free and it didn't block anything according to the logs. 3. I didn't test it with a hello world program. But it happened on other projects too. The projects i am working on are pretty small with max 25-30 header/source files.

Comment: If you just run your app using "start without debugging", how about the result? Do you debug it in other VS machine? Which dll file was loaded slowly during debugging? Maybe you could disable the Microsoft symbols Server, debug it again. If a simple app still has this issue, we would think about the VS IDE setup or the Windows Configuration. Check your task manager, whether the windows has the performance issue? Or you could repair your VS with the latest update 3.

Comment: I already have update 3 installed. Also i cannot look at the task manager or any other application while it is happening because all my applications and whole windows just freeze. It only happens on a rebuild after i changed something.

Comment: I found out that sometimes it doesn't even load dlls; it just crashes (doesn't respond) and if it does that windows doesn't respond too. It happens totally random when i rebuild my project.

Comment: Just to make this issue clearly, whether it has the crashed issue in debugging or just rebuild the project? Do you run your VS as the admin or test it in other VS machine? The dll files would be recompiled during rebuild, whether there are any third party library in your project's reference or the output folder? Maybe you forget to set the specific dll reference property "copy local=True", so it met certain issue when it try to find and load this dll file.

Comment: @ttgg1, any update? What about this issue?

Comment: It happens only on rebuilding. I always run it on my machine. If it happens VS is loading some standard dll.

Comment: @JackZhai, Just got an bluescreen of it and it froze when it completed gathering info data. I usually have other programs running when it happens if that helps (Spotify,Firefox).

Comment: In the logs i just fount the error code: `0x0000001a (0x0000000000061941, 0x0000000044f23000, 0x000000000000000d, 0xffff9b01b101ab00)`

Comment: @ttgg1, how about running your VS in safe mode using command line? Devenv/safemode. You'd better to check that whether all apps have the same issue, if a simple hello word app still has this issue, we would think about the VS setup or the Windows configuration.

Comment: @JackZhai, thanks for your help! i think i have figured it out: i have confused symbol loading and dll loading ... sorry ... the problem was that it froze on symbol loading from the Microsoft servers. I thought that it was normal that it takes like a minute to rebuild a project/file but it only took this long because it was loding the symbols. So i clicked on Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and disabled Microsoft Symbol Servers everything works fine now and recompiling only takes a few seconds.

Comment: @ttgg1, Glad to know that it has been resolved, if so, would you please post your comment as the solution(answer), and mark it as the answer. So it would help other members who meet the same issue as yours. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself: i clicked on **Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols** and disabled Microsoft Symbol Servers everything works fine now.